# Не могу найти элемент

Tags: c#, selenium

[image]

Выглядит вот так:

```
<a href="здесь ссылка" class="title-subject">Подтверждение эл. почты</a>
```

И больше ничего. Пытаюсь через селениум искать так:

```
        IWebElement pismo = loadpage.FindElement(By.ClassName("title-subject"));
        pismo.Click();
```

И так:

```
            IWebElement pismo = loadpage.FindElement(By.Name("title-subject"));
        pismo.Click();
```

Но всё равно выдаёт ошибку. Есть идеи?

Comment: Может ваш элемент внутри фрейма? Если так, то нужно сначала переключиться туда, потом искать

Comment: @suit Можно по-подробнее?)

Comment: У элемента, который ищете есть родительский элемент `frame` или `iframe`?

Answer (score -1):

```
IWebElement pismo = loadpage.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[class*='title-subject']"));
pismo.Click();
```